# How OpenDKIM decides which emails to sign?

Tags: email, email-server, dkim, opendkim

In OpenDKIM, what domain does it consider to use when comparing to internal hosts? Do it consider the domain of `Return-Path` (i.e. envelope `MAIL FROM`'s domain) or header `From` or `HELO`'s domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The introduction in [RFC 6376, 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376.html#section-1) binds DKIM with *Internet Message Format* [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). From that alone it is clear that it is about the message headers rather than the *envelope* sender ([RFC 5321, 2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.1)).

> DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) permits a person, role, or
> organization to claim some responsibility for a message by
> associating a domain name [[RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034)] with the message [[RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)],
> which they are authorized to use.

Furthermore, the [opendkim.conf(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/opendkim.conf.5.html) man page has a documentation for `SigningTable` parameter:

> Defines a  table used to select one or more signatures to apply to a message **based on the address found in the `From:` header field**. - -
>
> If the first field contains only a "`%`" character, it will be replaced by **the domain found in the `From:` header field**.  Similarly, within the optional second field, any "`%`" character will be replaced by the domain found in the `From:` header field.
>
> If this table specifies a regular expression file ("`refile`"),  then  the  keys  are  wildcard  patterns  that  are **matched against the address found in the `From:` header field**.  Entries are checked in the order in which they appear in the file.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. I just forgot that part